# Tiny repetitive scrolling in XCode 4.2 editor: What is it, and how do I turn it off?

Tags: xcode, editor

I recently upgraded Xcode 4.1 to 4.2.  The new editor has a 'feature' where the edit window scrolls to the left and back about 1/4 of an inch every so often  (about once every 40 seconds).   I don't know what it means, or why it happens, but it's driving me nuts.   Could someone please explain why this happens and how to turn off this "fantastic feature" ?  You will save my mental sanity.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this happen only when you are typing? Is this a notebook/laptop?

Comment: This is a laptop (macbook pro) with the latest OS.  I have a magic mouse.  It happens when I am moving the mouse to click on a spot in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed the same thing with my magic mouse, though I have an iMac.  What happens is we make a slight left-to-right or right-to-left swipe on the surface of the mouse which is interpreted as a request to browse back a page or forward a page respectively. Since it's just a slight gesture it makes just a little movement.

For a solution you can turn of the 'swipe between pages' support in system preferences under mouse. But honestly once you know not to do it it stops happening (for the most part), and I really like the web navigation swipes.

Comment: You are right.  Thanks.  This was driving me nuts.   Now I have to retrain my mouse handling not to move my index at all as I move the mouse.  I don't mind that.  At least I know what makes it happen.  I cannot click on the response counter since I don't have the required points for that.